# How not to write kernel warnings into /var/log/messages?

Tags: centos, kernel, logs, kvm, vps

I keep getting these log warnings due to a bug in `kvm`.

```
Jun 30 19:12:31 server kernel: kvm: 28882: cpu0 ignored rdmsr: 0x345
Jun 30 21:12:31 server kernel: kvm: 31191: cpu0 ignored rdmsr: 0x345
Jun 30 23:12:31 server kernel: kvm: 1107: cpu0 ignored rdmsr: 0x345
Jul  1 01:12:31 server kernel: kvm: 3583: cpu0 ignored rdmsr: 0x345
Jul  1 03:12:31 server kernel: kvm: 5940: cpu0 ignored rdmsr: 0x345
Jul  1 05:12:31 server kernel: kvm: 8409: cpu0 ignored rdmsr: 0x345
Jul  1 07:12:31 server kernel: kvm: 10682: cpu0 ignored rdmsr: 0x345
```

I tried changing values in printk file from `default` to `3  3  1  3` so that only critical logs are written in `/var/log/messages`. But these warnings won't go away.

Any idea to get rid of these warnings?

Comment: Which syslog daemon does your system run? sysklogd? rsyslog?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to edit your `/etc/rsyslog.conf` file by commenting the 9th line:

```
$ModLoad imklog   # provides kernel logging support (previously done by rklogd)
```

and then you have to restart `rsyslog` service:

```
#/etc/init.d/rsyslog restart
```

Comment: the command disables all kinds of kernel logs. Is there a command to disable only certain kernel logs?